# Windows 10 only display names after changing the keyboard to japanese

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Note: if this question is in the wrong section, please move to the correct one.

My problem is a bit strange.

After starting Windows 10 my keyboard is set to English format(default, I think). However any text that should be displayed does not appear, similar to the figure:

[image: Task manager]

The icons appear, but no text, even the tooltips becomes blank. Until I set my keyboard to Japanese(Microsoft IME), then if I reload any page that was affected the problem is solved and any future page is displayed correctly until I restart Windows again.

I really have no idea about what is happening, and even less on how to fix it.

Not sure if it gonna be of any help:

SO: Windows 10
Version: 2004
OS build: 19041.928
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack120.2212.551.0

Comment: Likely the default system font does not have the characters needed. Change it per https://www.howtogeek.com/716407/how-to-change-the-default-system-font-on-windows-10/ . If that doesn't help, use DISM and SFC to repair Windows - a safe but slow process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution presented by DrMoishe Pippik to no avail, since it seems to be corrupting slowly my PC, I decided to refresh Windows, which solved the problem along with others minor problems, such: boot time, and Windows always installing updates even when there are none.

Regardless, thanks for your comment DrMoishe Pippik, it helped me to find that slow corruption on Windows, otherwise, I might have notice too late.